# Mysql custom auto increment id to fix random ids

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have joined a project which has used client side generated random numbers for primary key fields within a mysql database. These primary key fields are auto-increment, but have not been used as such.

I think this was done because the developer did not know how to retrieve the database generated id after insertion.

We now have a sparse array of id values in many tables and a significant number of key collisions on insertion.

Is there some remedial work I can do to allow the database to generate the ids (i.e. start from the last allocated id and find the next available id) and for the following JDBC call to work?

```
numero = stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Comment: To be able to suggest you something practical you have to be much more specific and start from posting your current table schema and specify what engine you're currently using.

Comment: @peterm. Ok thanks. The db contains about 120 tables (to many to enumerate), each entity table contains a single surrogate primary key which is typically int(10) non-null auto_increment. The target db is mysql 5.1.69. The ids are 'well' spaced out across the id range i.e large gaps. The jdbc client is current. The existing code is dreadful with many mistakes and consequential data quality issues. I am looking for architectural advice which will work. E.g. implement a stored proc, update this mysql last id meta data field etc. Hoping that someone has come across this before and fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you search Google for 'generate database primary key from sequence MySQL' it will help.

Using sequences: Find the largest primary key in a given table, and create a sequence that increments by 1, starting with that largest primary key value. Create a separate sequence for each table. Note your are letting the database generate the key so you will have to disable the program or client from generating the key.

Alternately, you can create a brand new database schema that implements primary key generation correctly. Then migrate the data from the old database to the new one, populating parent tables before the child tables. Then, programmatically matching parent to child records based on the old priamry keys. However, I think this will be very time consuming for the size of your database.

Comment: Thanks. The current max(id) for some tables is already near the top of the available id range due to random spread so I would need to do a schema change to increase the field size. There is no doco/domain model and the ids are foreign keys in numerous other tables so if I miss one foreign key field schema change - things will blow up. Having said that I think increasing the field length and starting from max(id)+1 could be my best option.